# Is it possible to Create users in multiple domains using an APP registered in one single Azure Tenant. Using Graph Rest API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

If organisation is having multiple domains and a developer is trying to create a user using graph rest endpoint by using a app that is registered in one of the Azure tenant; Then in this case is it possible to create a  user to be created in another domain. Not able to understand. Appreciate help.

Comment: Do you have an issue with creating users? If those domains are in a single Azure AD tenant, and you have an app in that tenant with the appropriate permissions, you should be able to create users with any of those verified domains.

Answer (score 0):

An Azure AD application will need to be consented appropriate permissions in the domain that is will be targeting.  If you create a multi-tenant application then it should be able to be granted permissions in each target domain.  During authentication flow you will target "/common" instead of the individual Azure AD domain to get the appropriate access token.  See the following links for more information on creation and authentication.

[How to: Sign in any Azure Active Directory user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps)

[Tenancy in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)